# Fixing Google Places with wrong categories in my area

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I am working on an application in which i need the stores from where a person is standing, i started using Google Places but places marked in my city are all in the wrong "type" in the google database, e.g. There is a restaurant nearby by the name "XYZ" and its now showing under restaurants but in some "establishment" type... Is there a way i can fix these types ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All places are categorized under the type `establishment` until Google has enough metadata about a place to categorize it under more specific place types like `bar`, `cafe` and `restaurant`.

A work around that may find more results is to use the `keyword` parameter in your request with something like 'restaurant' as the value.

e.g.

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&keyword=restaurant&sensor=false&key=YOUR_API_KEY

As per the [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/): 
The `keyword` parameter is matched against all available fields, including but not limited to name, type, and address, as well as customer reviews and other third-party content.

You can also update the business listing information to include the correct type by following the instructions [here](http://support.google.com/maps/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=171429).

Comment: I tried Google Map Maker thingy, there is has catagories. Is it the same as types for Places?

Comment: @MohammadUmairKhan Places API types are derived from these categories, so make sure you select one that is as close to possible as the desired type on the Places API.